# How to change the Bug state to Committed when a Pull Request is made in Tfs2018

Tags: tfs, devops, scrum

Using Scrum process in TFS 2018 on-premises, I'd want to change the Bug(s) state to Committed when a developer creates a pull request that references Work Items.

Any idea how to accomplish that?

Answer (score 2):

You cannot achieve that automatically for now as no such a built-in feature in TFS. I have submitted a [user voice here](https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/330519-azure-devops-formerly-visual-studio-team-services/suggestions/35514094-customize-work-item-state-once-a-pr-is-created) for you to suggest the feature, you can go and vote it up to achieve that in future release...

However as a workaround you can update the state for a specific work item (Bug here) manually or by calling the REST API.

Please see [Fields - Update](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/vsts/wit/fields/update?view=vsts-rest-4.1) for details.

PowerShell for example:

```
Param(
   [string]$baseurl = "http://server:8080/tfs/DefaultCollection",  
   [string]$projectName = "0511ScrumTFVC",
   [string]$workitemid = "124",
   [string]$user = "domain\user",
   [string]$token = "Password"
)

# Base64-encodes the Personal Access Token (PAT) appropriately
$base64AuthInfo = [Convert]::ToBase64String([Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes(("{0}:{1}" -f $user,$token)))
write-host $WorkitemType

function CreateJsonBody
{

    $value = @"
[
  {
    "op": "test",
    "path": "/rev",
    "value": 2
  },
  {
    "op": "add",
    "path": "/fields/System.State",
    "value": "Committed"
  }

]

"@

 return $value
}

$json = CreateJsonBody

$uri = "$baseurl/_apis/wit/workitems/$($workitemid)?api-version=2.2"
Write-Host $uri
$result = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $uri -Method Patch -Body $json -ContentType "application/json-patch+json" -Headers @{Authorization=("Basic {0}" -f $base64AuthInfo)}
```

Comment: Microsoft could create a new action for this and we would customize the transition... `<ACTION value="Microsoft.VSTS.Actions.PullRequestCreated"/>`

Comment: @JobaDiniz Yeah, that makes sense, you could add the suggestion in the user voice.